# React Native text goes behind object

Tags: css, react-native, styling, z-order

Hi Guys I have an issue where some text is being overlapped by another object.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bOuz.png) of what's happening.

You can see that the second line of text is behind the white shape, how can I make it so it becomes above the white shape? Ive tried z order and various other positions but can't get my head round this.

The code for this:

code for the white square:

```
const Square = () => {
  return <View style={styles.square} />;
};
```

then the main code

```
<View style={{flex: 1, padding: 0}}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#8af542'}}>
          <View
            style={{
              marginTop: 150,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text>TEST</Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 140,
                zIndex: 1,
                elevation: 1,
              }}>
              TEXT HERE
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              marginBottom: windowHeight * -0.05,
            }}>
            <Square></Square>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      )}
    </View>
```

Then here are the styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centerItems: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  square: {
    width: windowWidth,
    height: windowHeight * 0.6,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: windowHeight * -0.05,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occuring because you have set the zIndex of the `TEXT HERE` view, and not the view that you want to have on the bottom. To resolve this, simply add the following to the square's view like so:

```
       <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          zIndex: 100
        }}>
        <Text>TEST</Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 140,
            zIndex: 1,
            elevation: 1,
          }}>
          TEXT HERE
        </Text>
      </View>
```

And then, if that does not help you, set the square's view `zIndex: -1` like so:

```
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          marginBottom: windowHeight * -0.05,
          zIndex: -1
        }}>
        <Square></Square>
      </View>
```

When doing this, we are essentially telling the views to switch positions, and the view with the whitespace is being forced to the bottom.